# Python, Fizz Buzz inserting the range as a parameter of the function

Tags: python, fizzbuzz

I am using the fizz buzz exercise to learn a little about python. I have hardcoded a range of 1-100 but I was curious how I might accomplish the same result by passing the range into the function using the parameter?

```
numbers = range (1,101)
def fizzbuzz(numbers):
    for each in numbers:
        if each % 3 == 0 and each % 5 == 0:
            print "fizzbuzz"
        elif each % 3 == 0:
            print "fizz"
        elif each % 5 == 0:
            print "buzz"
        else:
            print each
print fizzbuzz(numbers)
```

Comment: It looks like you know how to...

Comment: You mean `fizbuzz(range(3,201))`, or modifying the function to be called as `fizzbuzz(3, 201)`? You *already are* passing the range object in as a parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
def fizzbuzz(num_range):
    for each in num_range:
        if each % 3 == 0 and each % 5 == 0:
            print "fizzbuzz"
        elif each % 3 == 0:
            print "fizz"
        elif each % 5 == 0:
            print "buzz"
        else:
            print each

print fizzbuzz(range (1,101))
```

Comment: Or do something with optional params:

    def fizzbuzz(min = 1, max = 101):
        for each in range(min, max)

Answer (score 1):

You could use Python's itertools.count and pass in just the max value.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html

```
def fizzbuzz(num):
    for i in itertools.count(start=1,step=1):
        if (i==num):
            break
        ..fizzbuz logic

fizzbuzz(num)
```